# How to scale and center an image and make the space between images proportional

Tags: html, image, height, center

First, I apologize; I'm a designer, not a coder. I have to create a webpage to share a logo with clients. I've written something by trial and error that is a little better than good enough, but now I'd like to try and make it better.

The webpage consists solely of four images. I would like the topmost image to be centered and scaled to fit in the viewer's browser window. I've looked at sample code, and I can't get any of it to work. [Aside: Of the dozen samples I tried, none of them were remotely similar to each other. I'm amazed that there are so many ways to do the same thing—and yet I still couldn't figure it out.]

It would be great if the solution could fix an small issue I have with the page: The height of the top image scales to 75% of the window height (which fits horizontally 95%. of the time), but when viewed on a tall, narrow screen (like a phone), the right side of the image gets cut off. Is it possible to scale based on whether the window's height or width is smaller?

Finally, I would like to have space between the images which right now I achieve with padding. However, this means it's a fixed 50px regardless of the size of the images which scale proportionally to the window's width. Is it possible to make the padding 25% to the height of the image?

Thank you,
Pete

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Saltwater Logos</title>
    
    <style>
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
        
img.icon {
  height: 75vh;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
        
img.logo {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

</style>    
</head>
    
<body style="background-color:black;">
        <div>
            <img class="icon" src="logo/Icon.png" alt="Icon">
            <img class="logo" src="logo/Positive.jpg" alt="Positive" align="center">
            <img class="logo" src="logo/Negative.jpg" alt="Negative" align="center">
            <img class="logo" src="logo/BlackWhite.png" alt="Black & White" align="center">
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean that `<img class="icon" src="logo/Icon.png" alt="Icon">` is cut, right? Well, that's because you didn't write to rescale it.

When you define `img.logo`'s CSS, you write `height: 90%; width: 90%;`, which only tells to mantaign 90% proportion of the window. Meanwhile when you define `img.icon` you just write   `height: 75vh; width: auto;`, which is a fixed size. This way, if your monitor/screen is smaller than 75vh (which is 565.5px), the image will be cut (and not resized to fit in).

So, I think writing a percentage (like 100%) instead of a measure (like 75vh) as a value of height and width will do it.

Comment: If I change `img.icon` to `height: 75%; width: 75%;` then the bottom of the image is cropped on a wide screen. The issue is that most screens are horizontal, so defining the size of the image by the height will allow for the entire image to be shown. When the screen in taller than it is wide, then the right side of the image will be cropped. What I'm looking for is a way for the size of the image to be scaled according to which screen dimension is smaller.

I feel like there's a solution that involves drawing a box around the browser window and then putting the scaled image in that box.

Comment: Ok... _What I'm looking for is a way for the size of the image to be scaled according to which screen dimension is smaller_ is more clear. I would suggest to write a function to detect your screen's dimension and then set your images's dimension. You can do it by writing a JavaScript script and then inserting it into your HTML file.

Comment: Do you need help to do it? Right now I'm busy, but if you need anything later maybe I can help you

Comment: @JustCallMaA Thank you very much for your offer. If the solution was HTML/CSS which I might use again, I would take you up on it, but it's unlikely I'll use JavaScript anytime soon. You'd just windup doing the coding for me, and I'll never have the opportunity to use what I've learned. As the site is now, everything works better than good enough, and anything more is gilding the lily.Thanks again, though.